# How to troubleshoot sata problems?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, motherboard, sata

I got this issue where when the computer boots, sometimes it waits up to 30 seconds detecting the one sata drive, and sometimes after this period it just says that the sata drives are empty.

At first I thought this was a ram issue and I had ram issues earlier in the day because I stuck all my ram sticks from storage into the computer, it had 8 slots, and the sata would loose the disk in the middle of operation. I took out 7 of the sticks, did a one hour ram test, found no issues.

Now win 10 comes on for like 10 minutes in recovery mode and does check disk, however in the middle of check disk it still crashes before finishing with bad system config error.

So what? Is this motherboard fried or something? Is the sata controller intermittently malfunctioning?

Comment: Did you update the BIOS settings after changing the hardware configuration?

Comment: Have you tried booting from a live CD? incompatible ram sticks can cause bizarre issues, but if you are still down to one, that probably shouldn't be it. Do you have any M.2 or PCIE based storage (those usually cause certain sata ports to disable automatically, since the lane is devoted to the other socket; check your manual for details)? your OS may be damaged. so what is the error message the "bluescreen" displays?